# Any risks associated with habitually updating/reverting ALL features in drush?

Tags: 7, drush, features

I want to start using drush commands to simply update all or revert all features (depending on which environment I'm in) instead of doing them one by one. What are the risks involved or questions I should ask myself before habitually just updating all or reverting all features?

`drush fra` (to revert all on production and test servers)

`drush fua` (to update all on dev environment)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I do "**revert-all**" **all the time** (to test / roll out changes on Test and Production).
Because no feature update should be overlooked before / during release.

Personally, I would find **"update-all" way too risky**. Because Dev potentially contains many small tests, changes, trials, and failed attempts. Those should never slip into a (bloated) commit. Let alone reach a "revert-all" on Production.

An "update-all" would also conflict with my understanding of **"atomic commits"**. Where commits are always (many) small changes, exclusively.

Those are easily read. Easily understood. Easily undone. (And all features contain only small components (are not bloated).)

Changing a content-type? Do "drush fu this-content-type-feature". Commit.

Updating a view? If happy, then do "drush fu that-view-feature". Commit. Next.

Makes for very **readable** "git diff"s, without including any accidental or experimental changes from a Dev.

Comment: I've come to this conclusion also, perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, first and foremost thing which should be taken into consideration is that your feature should not have any changes different from your development environment.

secondly, make sure that all of the fields of a content type have same type and widget as that are in your production environment.

You can also take backup of the db before reverting the features in case you are making any major changes.